# `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined ` error while sending cross domain messages using EasyXDM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, easyxdm

I am trying to make a data exchange system between two websites at their client sides. I am using EasyXDM for this. (http://easyxdm.net/). Here is my code of parent website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>EasyXDM Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="easyXDM.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var serv_socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
            remote: "http://localhost:39452/EasyXDM/Default.aspx",
            onMessage: function (message, origin) {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerText="Received '" + message + "' from '" + origin + "'";
            },
            onReady: function () {
                serv_socket.postMessage("ID");
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:39452/EasyXDM/Default.aspx"></iframe>
        <input type="text" id="msgtext" /><a href="#" onclick="serv_socket.postMessage('d')">Send message</a>
        <div id="msg"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is the child website's code that is located at `localhost:39452` domain:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Server</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" id="msgtext" />
        <div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="easyXDM.debug.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
                    onMessage: function (message, origin) {
                        //document.getElementById('msg').innerText="Received '" + message + "' from '" + origin + "'";
                        socket.postMessage(message);
                    },
                    onReady: function (msg) {
                        socket.postMessage(msg);
                    }
                });
                function send() {
                    socket.postMessage('this is message from server');
                }
            </script>
            <a href="#" id="sender" onclick="send()">Send message</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that, when I click `Send message` on child website and call `socket.postMessage()` it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined.`. Please tell me how to solve this issue?

**Update:** `socket` is becoming null or undefined somehow.

Comment: Did you check that socket was properly initialized when your page loads, before clicking send? Shouldn't your script tag be in the head?

Comment: @rob thanks for the response. I finally found the answer and posted it. Check it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution finally here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13122604/1576363.
 I removed the `iframe` from parent and added `container` property of the socket to the `id` of a `div` and it worked. The reason for this was that the EasyXDM code automatically adds an `iframe` to your document. If you add `iframe` with the URL of child, you will get this error. From the linked answer, here is the clear explanation:

> The "consumer" is the parent document, and EasyXDM loads the
>   "provider" which is the child iframe.

Comment: there is so few people that have worked with easyXDM. May you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203172/easyxdm-download-files-from-3rd-party-service please?

Comment: Learned this the hard way this week